# iTextsharp and DataGrid color conflict

Tags: vb.net, itext

One DataGrid on my code personalized with code like

```
With MyDataGrid
    .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
End With
```

Works fine.

Using Nuget I installed iTextsharp using Install-Package iTextSharp and then I added the lines

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.BaseColor
```

The code works and the PDF was created

But if I add the line

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.Font
```

A conflict arise on the lines

```
With MyDataGrid
    .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
End With
```

Visual Studio says

> Property iTextSharp.text.Font.Color as BaseColor
>   Get/set the color of this font
>   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

I think Visual Studio confuses the Color.White property of the Datagrid with the one of iTextsharp's text.

But even using this code (outside the With MyDataGrid)

```
MyDataGrid.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
MyDataGrid.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
```

The conflict persist

**How can i avoid this conflict?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force it to use the system colors you want by explicitly using System.Drawing colors, so it won't try and grab the color prefix from your other itextsharp references:

```
    With MyDataGrid
        .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    End With
```

Comment: Easy solution! Thanks.